# Why grep doesn't find when searching part of the word?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have encountered several times the case when I want to search a part of the word, grep fails to find those matches. It works when I search full word.

For example, I need to find all files that contain "mysql_" word. Because I am dealing with legacy code that uses "mysql" instead of "mysqli" to work with a database, and want to see how much of the code uses "mysql".

Now, my command is

```
grep -rnw './' -e "mysql_"
```

or

```
grep -P -rnw '\bmysql_' .
```

This still doesn't work.

But if I type:

```
grep -rnw './' -e "mysql_query"
```

then of course, grep finds all matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using the '-w' parameter which means that your search pattern should occur as a full word (in other words, is delimited "non-word" characters):

> ```
>   -w, --word-regexp
>           Select only those lines containing matches that form  whole  words.   The
>           test  is  that  the matching substring must either be at the beginning of
>           the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it
>           must  be  either  at  the  end  of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word
>           constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters,  digits,
>           and the underscore.
> ```

Note that in a regex, an underscore is a "word" character..

Since `mysql_` only appears as part as a word (as in `mysql_query`), `grep -w` doesn't report it.